# Router cannot separate ip addresses on the same NIC (Vmware)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, centos, vmware-workstation

Here is the scenario of my problem.

My network topology: I have an ISP Router Technicolor TG797n v3 and i have a wireless access point set to be a client mode and connected to my PC via Ethernet so it's pretty much connected over WIFI.

I have also Vmware Workstation running Centos 7 as a web server. The host have a static ip address and the guest(Centos) have a static ip address as well everything is fine and i can ping from and to everything.

*NOTE : The guest(Centos) is being set to bridging mode so it's connected to the physical network directly using the same NIC for the host.

The problem is the router identify  the connected device not as two different devices so it chooses the device ip randomly because both of the host and the guest is on the same NIC and have the same mac address.

What i want is the router to identify the guest and the host which they are both on the same NIC as a different devices.
Any way of getting around this problem and force the router to identify two different devices with two different ip addresses on the same NIC with the same mac address.

Thanks

Comment: How did two devices get the same MAC address? I don't believe this happens under normal conditions.

Comment: because simply it's virtualization so the host which is the PC have a mac address which is physical NIC and the guest as a virtual machine by setting it to bridging mode and selecting the same adapter it uses the same physical mac address from the host. but each one of them have a separate static ip address on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the MAC address of the CentOS machine on startup.

You can do this via the `MACADDR` option in the [interface configuration files](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).